# Designing a Backspace key

Tags: c#, beginner, form, event-handling

I have designed a Backspace button (part of a keyboard which I am designing) in windows forms and it works perfect with no errors (the code works very good). This button deletes what is inside the textbox.

I just want to see other people's views and what they think about my code, so because I am new to c# I think there might be other better ways to design Backspace button. Can you please see if there are any silly unprofessional mistakes in my code?

```
private void buttonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        textBox1.Focus(); // set the textbox focused.

        if (textBox1.SelectionStart >= 0) //check if there is text to delete


        {
           int TxTindex = textBox1.SelectionStart; // save the index position

            if (textBox1.SelectedText.Length > 0)  //// check if there is selected text
            {

                textBox1.SelectedText = "";  


            }

            else
            {

                if (TxTindex >0 && TxTindex == textBox1.Text.Length) // check if there is text in texbox and check if index is at the end of text.

                {


                    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Remove(textBox1.Text.Length - 1, 1);
                    textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;

                }

                else // is the index is in between the text?
                {
                    if (TxTindex > 0) // check if there is text in texbox
                    {

                        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Remove(TxTindex - 1, 1);
                        textBox1.SelectionStart = TxTindex - 1; // to set the cursor position after the deleted number between the text.
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        return;
                    }

                }

            }
        }
        else
        {

            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just to be clear— this is a simulated on-screen keyboard?

Comment: 200_success. I dont know what do you exactly mean. it is a keyboard I am designing using C#. so you press a button and this keyboard pups up with textbox and you only can write on this textbox.

Comment: I don't see a difference in the cursor being at the end or somewhere in the middle of the text.

Comment: Is it one of [these on-screen things](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/fa/TreasuryDirectLoginScreen.PNG/695px-TreasuryDirectLoginScreen.PNG) rather than one of [these physical things](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0a/QWERTY_keyboard.jpg)?

Comment: Maarten Bodewes . if the cursor at the end then you must keep it at the end after deleting text (to be more realistic ). and if the cursor in the middle then you have to keep it in the middle otherwise it will jump at the end which is not realistic.

Comment: 200_success♦. yes on-screen.

Comment: @naouf Doesn't it in both cases move one to the left? Would [firing a keyboard event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) not be more logical?

Comment: Maarten Bodewes. yes it moves to the left in both cases. firing a keyboard event is logical but i dont want to use it. I have to design my own ;)

Comment: @naouf Please precede usernames with an @ ; that way they'll get a notification if you reply to them. If fact using the @ makes it easier for you, since using @ plus the first character of the username will usually suggest the full username.

Comment: The entire method body can be reduced to only 40 characters: `textBox1.Focus(); SendKeys.Send("{BS}");`

Comment: @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå . it worked like a magic. I am new to C# , can I use SendKeys.Send() inside another button to insert numbers in the textbox? thank you.

Comment: @naouf Sure! And for synchronous execution use `SendWait`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through a series of mechanical transformations, it's possible to simplify the code down to this:

```
private void buttonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Focus();

    if (textBox1.SelectionLength > 0)
    {
        textBox1.SelectedText = "";
    }
    else if (textBox1.SelectionStart > 0)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Remove(--textBox1.SelectionStart, 1);
    }
}
```

It's now simple enough that the code would be better without comments.

---

How I got there:

1. Both of your `else { return; }` are superfluous.
2. The `if (TxTindex >0 && TxTindex == textBox1.Text.Length)` case is a redundant special case; its `else` clause contains exactly the same code.

The code so far:

```
private void buttonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Focus(); // set the textbox focused.

    if (textBox1.SelectionStart >= 0) //check if there is text to delete
    {
        int TxTindex = textBox1.SelectionStart; // save the index position

        if (textBox1.SelectedText.Length > 0)  //// check if there is selected text
        {
            textBox1.SelectedText = "";  
        }
        else if (TxTindex > 0) // check if there is text in texbox
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Remove(TxTindex - 1, 1);
            textBox1.SelectionStart = TxTindex - 1; // to set the cursor position after the deleted number between the text.
        }
    }
}
```

3. The outer `if (textBox1.SelectionStart >= 0)` is redundant, since the `if (textBox1.SelectionText.Length > 0)` and `else if (TxtIndex > 0)` tests are both more specific.
4. `textBox1.SelectedText.Length` is better written as [`textBox1.SelectionLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionlength.aspx).
5. The `TxtIndex` variable (which would be better named `textIndex` to be consistent with `textBox1`) can be eliminated.

Answer (score 1):

This handler for the <kbd>Delete</kbd> button is very tightly coupled with one specific text field in a form.  If there is anything else in the form — another text field, or even a checkbox, then that `textBox1.Focus()` is going to be very jarring.

A better design would do this differently in one of two ways:

- Add a layer of indirection: broadcast key events, to be handled by an event handler that, in turn, manipulates the text field's contents.
- Synthesize key events, which get [injected into the native Windows event system](https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WindowsInput/Native/NativeMethods.cs).

Both approaches would involve a lot more code.  However, considering that the problem has already been solved by the library I linked to, you might as well just use that library.